# Differentiation (least squares estimators)

Tags: derivatives, implicit-differentiation

I am wondering the number '-2' as you can see in the equation below.

I don't know how does this number come from...

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

$\beta_0$ appears with a minus sign before it. You're using the chain rule.

See this example:
$
\frac{\partial(-x)}{\partial x} = -1
$

Comment: Thanks!
Then may I also ask you to why the β_0 becomes (β_0 ) ̂?

Comment: I am afraid I need to have more context on what the hats mean....

Comment: @kim I think that just means that $\hat{\beta_0}$ are the arguments for which the derivative is $0$ (note that you are setting your derivative to $0$), i.e your estimators in this context